# Call to variable address

Tags: disassembly

I have come across the following instructions:

```
mov ecx, [ebp + var_4]
imul ecx, 4
call dword_1423d4[ecx]
```

Can someone explain to me what it possibly means or point me in the right direction? Why is the call made to a variable?

Comment: Calls function by reference out of an array of pointers?

Comment: @PSS what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dword_1423d4` is a pointer to a global array of 32-bit function pointers.

`var_4` is an index into this array.

The `call` instruction calls the function at index `var_4` in the `dword_1423d4` function array.

Comment: it's a common representation of a "switch()" statement when the values are linear.  The var_4 is the parameter to the switch(), the dword_1423d4 is the table of case handlers.

Comment: @peterferrie - From my experience, `switch` statements are typically compiled to use `jmp`, not `call`, but I suppose a compiler might choose the latter in some circumstances.

Comment: I agree with Jason, it is unlikely (although not guaranteed) to be a switch statement due to the call and no jmp. Possibly a custom function dispatcher or something.

Comment: Also agree with @JasonGeffner. I've never seen a `switch` statement (or anything aside from a real function call, for that matter) on x86 implemented with a `call` instruction.

Comment: By the way @JasonGeffner, I thought your [name sounded familiar](http://www.blackhat.com/html/bh-us-11/training/bh-us-11-training_sl-advmal.html) from BlackHat a couple years back.

Answer (score 1):

What immediately comes to mind is some type of virtualization layer accessing an IAT or IVT.  I absolutely agree with the previous answer that this is a call to a function vector in an array of function pointers.  I also agree that it does not look like a switch statement.  That's what takes me down the interrupt vector table/address table.

Comment: Would you please add more details into your answer? How is it different from the answer above? At the moment, it reads like a kudos to Jason's answer. If that is what you intended, you can show your agreement with another answer by clicking on the upvote button next to it. Posting a separate answer is not needed.

Comment: I must have missed a reference to an interrupt vector or address table in his answer.